# How to add default value in cakephp select option?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to add default select option in input field 
For example if I right this code

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'options' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'empty' => '(choose one)'
));
```

I want to change this code like

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'options' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'default' => options[1];  // it's not correct, I just want to add 2 as a default value.
));
```

Here I want to add option 2 as a default value.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the PHP you've written. You're attempting to reference something that doesn't exist for your `default` and isn't a proper PHP variable:-

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'options' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'default' => options[1];  // it's not correct, I just want to add 2 as a default value.
));
```

`options[1]` is not a valid PHP variable as you're missing the `$` symbol and the `$options` array hasn't been defined. You've just passed an array to the `options` attribute of your `input`.

You need to define the `$options` array first and then pass that to `$this->Form->input()` like this:-

```
$options = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'options' => $options,
    'default' => $options[1]; // '2' in the defined array
));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#common-options)

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'options' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'default' => '2'
));
```

Comment: If my input is like   echo $this->Form->input('book_category_id');   , If I want 2nd data will be default then is it possible in your code ?

Comment: Did you take the data from the database, and fill options in the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$options = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$attributes = array('value' => 2, 'empty' => false);
echo $this->Form->select('field', $options,$attributes);
```

This is the [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select) from cookbook

and if you are fetching result from database and then populating in select option then just put the value in `$this->request->data['Model']['field'] = 'value';` in controller and it will be default value in select dropdown

Comment: This does not set the default value. `value` will override any value set in `$this->request->data` which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->Form->control('name',['options' => $agents,'name'=>'name' ,'empty' => 'choose one','required']);
```