# How to set the 2nd drop down value to be the default value when the page loads using jquery using a database?

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql, cakephp

In options I am getting 2 values in that i want 2nd value as the default one

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->control(
    'course_id', 
     array(
      'type' => 'select', 
      'options' => $course_list, 
      'class' => 'form-control select2-show-search search_dropdown get-next-child','required',
      'id' => 'course_id',
      "label" => false
    )
  ); 
?>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
  <script>
    $(document).load(function () {
      var targetid = 'Commerce';
      if (targetid != null) {
        //$("select#selId").find("targetid").attr("selected", true);
        $("#course_id").val(targetid);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

I need "Commerce" as default value in the drop-down when page loads. Can anyone help?

Comment: Either put it first in the list, or add the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` tag. Doubt you need jquery for this, but we have no other context to work with.

Comment: @ADyson , in frontend used like this 'options'=>$course_list this $course_list variable has 2 values in that i want 2nd one has default in drop down

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide clarifications, and give proper details not just tiny code snippets out of context. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33646607/5947043 ?

Comment: @ADyson yes but tried with the default attribute but not working so using jquery

Comment: What version of cakePHP do you have?

Comment: @ADyson 3.9version

Comment: Ok. Here's the documentation for it, seems you should set the "value" attribute: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#checkbox-radio-select-options

Comment: Unfortunately the form helper docs are a little bit confusing, the correct option to use here is `default`, as `value` will override request data, see **https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#common-options-for-specific-controls**. Also you have to provide the actual value, not the label, which, according to the field name, is an ID, so most likely an integer value, the primary key of the course.

Comment: @ADyson Already tried using default attribute and value attribute but not working due to values are fetching from the database

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. A value is a value, no matter where it came from. Maybe provide a [mre] of that issue then we can try to see what's really happening